# Whenever I make a pull request, the new updates goes directly to EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2

Whenever I make a pull request. all the changes I made to my repo go to EC2 server on AWS directly without approval

this is how my node.js.yml file looks like

```yaml
# This workflow will do a clean installation of node dependencies, cache/restore them, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-nodejs

name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "development" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "development" ]

jobs: 
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    # - run: fuser -k 4000/tcp & fuser -k 4001/tcp 
    - run: yarn install
    - run: yarn build
    - run: pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
```

I tried deleting the following 2 lines but it didn't work.

```yaml
  push:
    branches: [ "development" ]
```

Comment: If you want to stop this behavior for pull requests, then I suggest deleting the `pull_request` section, not the `push` section.

Comment: That snippet doesn't deploy to a ec2 server, it starts your app on the CI runner.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do two things:

```yaml
on:
  # First change the target branch to main or uat
  # this will make sure that only push events to main or uat branch 
  # triggers a workflow instead of dev
  push:
    branches: [ "uat" ]
  # Second, remove the pull request trigger
  # Using push trigger for this simple case should suffice.
  # pull_request:
  #  branches: [ "development"]
```